# Using Simulations to determine probability sequence in Python

Tags: python

I have this question and I am not getting the result of the requirement.

Consider tossing a fair coin 20 times. Use simulations in Python to estimate:
(a) The probability of there being a sequence of exactly 5 heads in a row.
(b) The probability of there being a sequence of at least 5 heads or tails in a row?

```
import random
def coin_trial():
    heads = 0
    for i in range(20):
        if random.random() <= 0.5:
            heads +=1
    return heads

def simulate(n):
   trials = []
   for i in range(n):
       trials.append(coin_trial())
   return(sum(trials)/n)
   
simulate(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In the code you provided, you don't show any effort to check whether there are any heads or tails arranged 5 in a row, or done any probability calculations. Please complete your [mcve] by showing your efforts to solve those portions of the question so that we can better understand your difficulties

Comment: Thank you G Anderson..I’m kinda new to python and I have been trying to figure it out.

Comment: From the code it seems like you do not understand the concept of simulation at all. You have 20 coin tosses, but you need to repeat these 20 tosses at least hundreds or thousands of times, and from the analysis of these many tosses you estimate the probability

Comment: @ Jan Stransky I ran this more than a thousand times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. using `choice`

```py
import random
from numpy.random import choice

def coin_trial():
    trials = []
    for i in range(20):
        trials.append(choice([0, 1], p=[0.5, 0.5]))
    return trials

def sequence_n_heads(trials, n):
    return sequence_n_trials(trials, n, n)

def sequence_n_tails(trials, n):
    return sequence_n_trials(trials, n, 0)

def sequence_n_trials(trials, n, target):
    case = 0
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(trials)-n:
        if sum(trials[idx:idx+n]) == target:
            case += 1
            idx += 5
        else:
            idx += 1
    return case

def simulate(n):
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    for i in range(n):
        trials = coin_trial()
        heads += sequence_n_heads(trials, 5)
        tails += sequence_n_tails(trials, 5)
        
    return heads/n, tails/n
   
heads, tails = simulate(10)
print(heads, tails)
```